# Deleting a product with related pictures with PHP

Tags: php, unlink

In my PHP application I have products which have images in 3 sizes - big, thumbnails and small thumbnails. Each image is stored in a separate folder:

Images - /gallery
Thumbnails - /gallery/bigthumbs
Small thumbnails - /gallery/thumbs

Each product has its unique ID. The file names of all images of a certain product are the same. The path to the images for the product are being stored in the database with the same ID as the associated product ID.

Each product can have more than 1 image but in the database, where I store the paths and the names of the images for each product, all the images are stored with the same ID, the same as the product ID.

So, if a product with ID 56 has 2 images in the database, those images will be stored like this:

ID->56, image1name, bigthumb1name, thumb1name
ID->56, image2name, bigthumb2name, thumb2name

What I'm trying to do is - delete all the images associated with the product which is being deleted. The code I've written is as follows:

```
$imagename_query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM gallery WHERE id='$productid'", $connect);

$imagename_result = mysql_fetch_array($imagename_query);


    foreach($imagename_result as $imagename) {

    $bigimage = "../gallery/$imagename";
    unlink($bigimage);

    $picture = "../gallery/bigthumbs/$imagename";
    unlink($picture);

    $thumb = "../gallery/thumbs/$imagename";
    unlink($thumb);

 }

$gallery_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id='$productid'", $connect); 


$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE ID='$productid'", $connect);
```

The problem is that the code above deletes only 1 image - no difference how many images there are with the same ID.

Could anybody help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems suspect... Though I doubt it will give you anything useful, does `mysql_error()` say anything following your first `DELETE` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for help. I've managed to solve this in the following way:

```
$imagename_query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM gallery WHERE id='$productid'", $connect);

    $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($imagename_query);

for($i=0; $i<$rows_count; $i++){

    $id = mysql_result($imagename_query, $i, 'image');

    $bigimage = "../gallery/$id";
    unlink($bigimage);

    $picture = "../gallery/bigthumbs/$id";
    unlink($picture);

    $thumb = "../gallery/thumbs/$id";
    unlink($thumb);
}
```

Hope this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

this line is the problem

```
$imagename_result = mysql_fetch_array($imagename_query);
```

should be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($imagename_query))
{
  $bigimage = "../gallery/{$row['image']}";
  unlink($bigimage);
  // etc
}
```

I not sure is it truth for your case -- do you have multiple products with same name?

your approach could be a bit risky ...
you can make the folder path unique by embed the product id

such as

```
/gallery/{$product_id}/{$product_name}.*
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still deletes only 1 image per folder.

Comment: Before you do the deletion, can you do a check using a bash like `ls -l ../gallery/$product_name` ? This is to ensure there are always have more than one image in the folder

Comment: But it should go through the array elements, correct? Why doesn't it see that there's more than 1 element in the array? Why should it check the availability of other images in the folder?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row);` inside the while loop to let us know what are the information return by MySQL. And do a `ls -l` to check is all images are available

Comment: var_dump($row); does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

since you have more images you shoud use:

```
while ($current_imagename_result = mysql_fetch_array($imagename_query))
```

instead of

```
$imagename_result = mysql_fetch_array($imagename_query);
```

and after you will have to use `$current_imagename_resul`t instead of yor varable

Comment: di u try try printing printing for each cycle... just to see what do you get?

Comment: It prints the file name of one image only. Why could this happen? Why wouldn't all the images be added to the array?

Comment: try ro pass one of this parameters (MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM,MYSQL_BOTH) as second parameter of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: sorry... i'll keep thinking...
did u try to execute the query somewhere else just to b sure is returning more than one element?? seams to strange!